# Behavior of NSDateFormatter in iOS 5.1 and iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

Anyone else noticing some differences between iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.0?  In the following, the format of the date string comes back differently in each version:NSDateFormatter

```
*dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss (vvvvv)";
NSDate   *lDate   = [[NSDate alloc]init];
NSString *sDate   = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lDate];
```

In iOS 5.1, sDate is "10/01/2012 16:43:09 (GMT-05:00)"
but in iOS 6.0, sDate is "10/01/2012 16:44:09 ()"

Any ideas on why this would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss (vvvvv)";` with `@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss ('GMT'Z)";`

The `Z` format string will output what you were doing with `vvvvv` except for the `GMT` prefix and there is no colon as well.

If the colon is needed, you can add this line to add it to the string:

```
sDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [sDate substringToIndex:sDate.length-3], [sDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(sDate.length-3, 3)]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this solve your problem (only use one v):

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss (V)";
NSDate   *lDate   = [[NSDate alloc]init];
NSString *sDate   = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lDate];
```

Comment: You can view all date formatters used in iOS6 in this [link](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 1):

I have IST instead of GMT. I used `V` for that in IOS 5 working fine but in IOS 6 not working.